# openerp error : SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: odoo

Hello everyone I work on openerp 7.0 and I get the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\cli\server.py", line 98, in preload_registry
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 192, in get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 214, in new
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 343, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 258, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 161, in load_module_graph
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 133, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\openerp\addons\feicom_account_cm\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\openerp\addons\feicom_account_cm\model\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\openerp\addons\feicom_account_cm\model\treasury\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130227-002113\Server\server\openerp\addons\feicom_account_cm\model\treasury\treasury_committment.py", line 50
     [('hr.employee' , 'Employé'), ('res.partner' , 'Partenaire')], size=255,
 SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

the line that generates the error is:

```
'recipient_id' : fields.reference(string='Bénéficiare',[('hr.employee' , 'Employé'), ('res.partner' , 'Partenaire')], size=255,readonly=True, required=True,states={'draft':[('readonly', False)], 'canceled':[('readonly', False)]}),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to define like this way:

```
'recipient_id' : fields.reference('Bénéficiare',[('hr.employee' , 'Employé'), ('res.partner' , 'Partenaire')], size=255,readonly=True, required=Truee t,states={'draft':[('readonly', False)], 'canceled':[('readonly', False)]}),
```

What wrong you did here is you  have passed string like this way string='Bénéficiare' but you have to give like this way ('Bénéficiare',.....) **remove string=**

Hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use string at last or at least after domain.

```
'recipient_id' : fields.reference([('hr.employee' , 'Employé'), ('res.partner' , 'Partenaire')], size=255,readonly=True, required=True,states={'draft':[('readonly', False)], 'canceled':[('readonly', False)]},string='Bénéficiare'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem he had written: 
'recipient id': field.reference (string = 'Beneficiary' selection = [('hr.employee', 'Employee'), ('res.partner', 'Partner')], size = 255, readonly = True , required = True, states = {'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'Canceled': [('readonly', False)]})